How can I use GTM to track 3rd party widget events?
I have a table booking widget (3rd party) in one page of my website and I want to send the successful booking events to my GA4. I have the same GTM ID in my website and implemented in the vendor's backend.
I have created the tags that fires on successful events for FB Pixel, for example, with all the parameters to GA4 Event. But I can't see these events in GA4 Debugview.
The widget does push event to the data layer.
Google Tag is also firing 2x because of the widget.
How can I work around it? :(
